# RXJS Websocket Subject subscribing issues

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I've got a service class (Ang 8+) that manages websocket creation by using `rxjs/webSocket()` factory:

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketChannel {
    //................
    create(url?: string): Observable<WebSocketPackage<any>> { 
        this.wsSubj = webSocket<WebSocketPackage<any>>(this.channelUrl);
        this.wsSubj.pipe(
          retryWhen(errors => 
            errors.pipe(
              tap(err => {
                console.error('Websocket error', err);
              }),          
              delay(1000),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .subscribe(
          ok => console.log('ok'),
          ko => console.log('ko'),
        );
        return this.wsSubj;
      }
```

And a component that consumes the `wsSubj` member in its ngOnInit method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.wsManager.create();
    this.wsManager.wsSubj
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('HomeComponent WS OK');
      },
      err => {
        console.log('HomeComponent WS ERROR CATCH');
      },
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
  }
```

Here is my console.logs after some server stops/starts:

> //Websocket server UP
>
> websocket-manager.ts: ok
>
> component.ts: HomeComponent WS OK
>
> //Websocket server DOWN
>
> component.ts: HomeComponent WS ERROR CATCH
>
> websocket-manager.ts: 'Websocket error'
>
> //Websocket server UP
>
> websocket-manager.ts: ok
>
> //Websocket server DOWN
>
> websocket-manager.ts: 'Websocket error'

Long story made short, after the first 'server down' event, no emits reach the component anymore, but the subscribe inside the websocket-manager still works well.

Why? What I have to do in order to reach the component after the first down event?

Comment: look how you handled subscription inside of create with the help of `.retryWhen`. it is not applied to the subject you reveal to the "outer world". if you want to reveal it do `this.wsSubj = webSocket(...).pipe(retryWhen...)`

Comment: @Andrei I know, it's wanted, cause if I use the first one, no error are emitted to the component observer